Bluetooth headset connect but not recognized as audio device on windows 11
Earbuds used to work perfect. This issue just popped up randomly when I switched earbud. No amount of reddit posts, windows help centers and random forums have been able to help with this issue.
I have narrowed down the issue to bluetooth services. When I connect my Sony Linkbuds S it shows up as connected, but not with audio or microphone. In Input and output devices it doesn't show up either (yes I have checked hidden devices). The only way I can get them to work is to either
A. Disable audio sink in bluetooth services, but this makes the earbuds go in handsfree mode, which is great for calling but shit for listening to music while I work on other things. This is obviously not what I want.
B. Turn audio sink off and on repeatedly until they eventually show up/pair/connect correctly. When it works its completely by chance and I have to turn it off and on anywhere between 3 to 10+ or so times. They pair fine to my windows 10 desktop
I have tried the following to fix this issue

Reinstall bluetooth driver multiple times (Intel(R) Wireless Bluetooth(R))
Reinstall audio driver (Realtek audio)
Reinstall bluetooth earbuds driver in device manager
Re-pair about 20 times
Disable bluetooth on my phone in case it somehow pairs to two devices, which it shouldnt
Completely reset earbuds
Restart bluetooth support service and set startup to automatic
Make sure device isnt disable in input and output devices
Disable the thing where applications can take control of the output device

Please help this is driving me nuts

Have you tried the earbuds with another computer?

@harrymc they pair fine to my windows 10 desktop
